# Do I have to have each .net framework developer pack installed?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I have .net framework 4.5.2 installed.  The current (latest) .net Framework version is 4.8.  I have a project that needs some work that was created with version 4.6.2.  Must I download each framework release that I might need or can I download the current and be able to build or edit any prior version?

Comment: You only need one, it is backwards compatible with previous versions.

Comment: @HansPassant the later versions may also include bug fixes identified in earlier versions

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Microsoft documentation. The framework is backwards compatible so you can install the latest version and work will the 4.5.2 app you mentioned

[.NET Framework compaitibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility)

The docs are very useful for this kind of information